# How to get nginx running exact port on linux

Tags: shell

If i execute the below comment, The result will be like this **8060 0.0.0.0**

**netstat -antup | grep nginx |awk '{print $4 "\t" $5 }' | cut -d ":" -f2**

But I want the result to be like this **8060**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the orignial response from the command is, but just cut the response again is one way

```
netstat -antup | grep nginx |awk '{print $4 "\t" $5 }' | cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d " " -f1
```

Comment: **8060    0.0.0.0**
**8060    192.168.1.21**    
It came like this

Answer (score 1):

Deconstructing the command you provided, `netstat -antup` prints these information:

```bash
$ netstat -antup
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      XYZ/nginx
...
```

You want just the "8060", which is the port, nginx is listening to.

The next part was fine. `grep nginx |awk '{print $4}'` gives you the corresponding Local Address. You don't need the `"\t" $5` part, as the Foreign Address is not relevant here.

The intermediary result should look like this:

```bash
$ netstat -antup | grep nginx | awk '{print $4}'
127.0.0.1:8060
```

Now the port ist the last part after a ":". Be aware, that IPv6 addresses also contain ":"s. So i'd suggest to cut the very last one instead of the 2nd.
You can do so, by reverting the output, cutting the first bit and reverting again:

```bash
$ netstat -antup | grep nginx | awk '{print $4}' | rev | cut -d":" -f1 | rev
8060
```

et voila. the desired output